# "Parkplatz für/mit eine/r Wohnung"

Tags: preposition, collocation

What is the idiomatic preposition in the following sentence?

> Ich möchte gern einen Parkplatz **für die**/**mit der** Wohnung mieten

Perhaps more generally, I am looking for a suitable equivalent of "along with" that is not quite "dazu" in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

> > Ich möchte gern einen Parkplatz **für die**/**mit der** Wohnung mieten

As far I understand you correctly you *"along with"* should be translated to

> Ich möchte gerne einen Parkplatz **mit der** Wohnung mieten

Sound that you like to ask the proprietor to offer you a parking lot or garage along wit the flat.

More precisely you could say

> Ich möchte gerne einen Parkplatz **zusammen mit der** Wohnung mieten

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I would start this sentence the other way around, not with "Ich".

Using other translations makes it sound like non-native german to me.

"Ich möchte gerne einen Parkplatz zur Wohnung mieten".

"Dazu möchte ich gerne einen Parkplatz mieten."

"Zusätzlich möchte ich (zur Wohnung) einen Parkplatz mieten."

"dazu" in this context would be synonymize with "zusätzlich" which translates into "additionally"

The "Parkplatz" has a belonging relationship to "Wohnung" which is why you would say:
"Der Parkplatz gehört zur Wohnung."

"The parking space (belongs to)/(is part of) the appartment."

It sounds like your context is something close to an application for an appartment. If that's the case I would defo use:
"Zusätzlich möchte ich (zur Wohnung) einen Parkplatz mieten."